# Probabilty of Specific Output amongst 4 Outputs with Error Rates

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A computer has printer (P), disk (D), terminal (T), and magnetic (M) outputs. 55% of all output is on D, 25% are on P, 15% are on T, and 5% are on M. The error rate for D is 1/2000, for P it is 2/1000, for T it is 1/1000, and for M it is 1/500. An experiment is conducted where a character is output and we observe whether:

1. What device made the output
2. If the character is correct

What is the sample space? And what is the probability that the character was written on the disk, given A={it was incorrect}.

From my understanding this question requires the use of Bayes rule. However I'm not exactly sure how to apply it.

Comment: A natural sample space is the set of ordered pairs of the shape $(X,y)$, where $X$ is one of the device names, and $y$ is $1$ (for correct) or $0$ (for incorrect).

Comment: I'm not to sure what that means. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The sample space is the collection of possible results of the experiment. These results can be summarized by giving two items of information: a) the device that produced the character and (b) whether the character was correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the obvious abbreviations, we want $\Pr(D|A)$, the conditional probability that the device used was the disk, **given** that the result was incorrect.

We will use the **definition** of conditional probability, which is close to Bayes's Rule, but not exactly the same. By definition, we have
$$\Pr(D|A)=\frac{\Pr(D\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}.$$
Now we compute the probabilities on the right.

First we find the harder one, $\Pr(A)$. An error can happen in $4$ disjoint ways: (i) We used P, and got an error; (ii) We used D and got an error; We used T and got an error; (iv) We used M and got an error.

The probability we used P is, we are told, $\frac{25}{100}$. (Check this, the order of the letters changes during your post.) Given that we used P, the probability that $A$ happened (we had an error) is $\frac{2}{1000}$. Thus the probability of (i) is $\frac{25}{100}\cdot\frac{2}{1000}$.

The probabilities of (ii), (iii), and (iv) are computed in a similar way. For the probability of $A$, add up.

Finally, we need $\Pr(D\cap A)$. We know how to compute this, it is the probability of (ii).

Comment: I have received $ \frac{11}{41}$ as an answer for $\Pr(D|A)=\frac{\Pr(D\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}$ Not sure if you worked it out but does that sound correct?

Comment: I did not notice this before, but the probabilities of using the various devices do not add up to $100\%$. So there may be a typo in the original, or a typo in your transcription of the problem. With the probabilities as given, we cannot solve the problem, since there must be a mysterious fifth device we know nothing about.

Comment: I actually realized that myself, but it was a simple typo, D is 55%. I have edited the main question.

Comment: My arithmetic is lousy, but I get $\frac{11}{31}$.